# RSA with p and q being generated by pow expression of weak random seed

Tags: rsa, seed

n, e and modulus of RSA are given and n is very large. p and q are primes generated by `pow(7, random_seed, modulus)`, and the seed that p and q used is very close. How can I get p and q, or is there any other way to decrypt this RSA?

Comment: $n$ is calculated using $p$ and $q$. How is the `modulus` set in the given algorithm? How did you make sure that the result is indeed prime? Is this some kind of riddle, assignment, CTF or homework?